# Laravel: FormRequest validation extension isn't running

Tags: laravel

I need to write validation for pending invites and checking if one doesn't already exist.

Before I can get to that point, I'm just seeing whether my validation extension is running at all. It isn't.

I've tried the following:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Account;

use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;


class InvitedUser extends FormRequest
{

    public function __construct(ValidationFactory $validationFactory)
    {


        $validationFactory->extend(
            'no-pending-invites',
            function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
               return false;
            },
            'There is already a pending invite for this email'
        );

    }

... 

public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|max:255|email|no-pending-invites',
            'role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        ];
    }
```

The constructor method isn't failing. I then tried this instead:

```
public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->addExtension('no-pending-invites', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return false;
        });

        $validator->addReplacer('no-pending-invites', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters, $validator) {
            return __("There is a pending invite for :attribute already", compact('attribute'));
        });
    }
```

This doesn't fail either. My tests pass with no validation issues.

How can I add custom validation to one of my FormRequest validators if the above method do not work?

Comment: Did you try to add it directly to the `rules`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a closure instead on my `rules()`

```
public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'max:255',
                'email',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                    $account_id = $request->session()->get('account_id');

                    $invitedUser = InvitedUserModel::where('account_id', $account_id)
                            ->where('email', $value)
                            ->first();


                    if (!$invitedUser->expired()) {
                        $fail('A pending invite for the email "'. $value .'" already exists.');
                    }

                },
            ],
            'role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        ];
    }
```